# jquery faq for table

Tags: jquery

when i pressed a link all the td's are shown.
how can i hide and show each td when pressed?

```
    <head>

<style type="text/css">
.details{display:none;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$().ready(function() {
    $('a.buy').click(function() {
        $('.details').slideToggle('fast', function() {
        });
    });
});
</script>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td> <a class="buy" href="#">more details</a> </td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="details">text 1 text 1 text 1 text 1 </td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td> <a class="buy" href="#">more details</a> </td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="details">text 2 text 2 text 2 text 2 </td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td> <a class="buy" href="#">more details</a> </td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="details">text 3 text 3 text 3 text 3 </td>
    </tr>
</table>              

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How would you click a hidden `td` to make it visible:D ??

Answer (score 0):

`$('.details')` addresses *all* cells with this class. You must specifically target the one you want:

```
$(this) // <-- this is the currently clicked link
  .closest('tr') // <-- go up until the next tr
  .next() // <-- next tr
  .find('td.details').show(); // <-- show the cell there
```

If you want to hide all others, you can simply hide *all* before showing the one you want:

```
$('.details').hide();
// then the above
```

This is not particularly performant, but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of .closest() and .find() jquery functions to achieve this. Here is the working example in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AGnwZ/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `<dl> <dt> <dd>` in HTML ( best fit )

### HTML

```
<dl class="faq">
<span style="font-size: 14px; ">
<span class="Apple-style-span" style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; ">
    <dt><span style="color: rgb(10, 171, 253); ">Question?</dt>

    <dd>Answer.<a class="close" href="#">Close Text</a></dd> 
</span>
</span>
</dl>
```

### jQuery

```
$('.faq dd').hide(); 

$('.faq dt').click(function(){ 
        $(this).next('dd').slideToggle('slow'); 
});    
$('a.close').click(function (){ $(this).parent('dd').slideUp('slow'); });
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xkeshav/nEsAq/)